# Google maps on my website Problems

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I PHPLD and the maps function isn't working properly. When I asked them, I will need to pay for support (even though support was included in the purchase of the program). So, I've tried to fix it myself.

My problem started that addresses couldn't be found (I'm in Cambodia, there aren't many road names, street names, etc).

I managed to add Latitude and Longitude to the database and call them for the maps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
addressElements.push({ldelim}
id: "map",
value: '{$LINK.LATITUDE},{$LINK.LONGITUDE}',
content: '<div class="map_infomain"><div class="map_infowindow"><div class="map_infotitle">{$LINK.TITLE|replace:"'":"\\'"} </div><div class="map_infodesc">{$LINK.ADDRESS|trim|replace:"'":"\\'"}{if $LINK.CITY != ""}<br> {$LINK.CITY}{/if}{if $LINK.STATE != ""}, {$LINK.STATE}{/if}{if $LINK.ZIP != ""}<br> {$LINK.ZIP}{/if}{if $LINK.PHONE_NUMBER != ""}<br> {$LINK.PHONE_NUMBER}{/if}</div>{if $LINK.IMAGE}<div class="map_infoimg"><img width="100" height="100" src="{$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/uploads/thumb/{$LINK.IMAGE}" border="0" /></div>{/if}</div></div>'
{rdelim});
</script>
```

The only problem is that they don't seem to appear in the same place as they do on google maps.

Here's my website:

http://www.camuk-directory.com/listing/haks-house-6

Here's the Google maps location:

https://www.google.com/maps/@13.348013,103.8458084,20z

It's always down the road a bit or one another road very nearby!

It's all done with Javascript and the code is on my website.

Is this normal for Google Maps when using it on a website? I've gone all through the code, but I'm not really good at Javascript. I managed to change the information and create new tables in my database and use that on the website, but I want it more precise!

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with different addresses , facing same problem?

Comment: Hi, I actually deleted that address now and most addresses seem to be fairly close. I would say about 75% are close. The other 25% can be as much as 1km away from the actual place, even though I'm using Longitude and Latitude, it still puts some at the wrong location!